# What is the proper procedure after rebasing

Tags: git, github

I read contradictory things about how to proceed with git rebase so I would like to ask:

**The background**

- I have a remote repository with a branch master
- I have a local version of the repo and I create a branch to do my work
- I push the branch and I create a merge review

Later

- Someone advanced the repository and now origin/master is some commits ahead

**What I did**

- I fetched master `git fetch origin master`
- `git checkout master`
- `git merge origin/master`
- `git checkout myBranch`
- `git rebase master`

So now I have myBranch rebased over the new master but these two things happen

**The problem**

1. There is a branch `origin/myBranch` left in the local repo
2. I cannot push myBranch to the repo (unless I do it forcefully)

So, I am not asking how should I solve this
What I am asking is, what is the proper procedure to integrate changes to the remote myBranch, what am I doing wrong in what I described, and is forceful push the only way?

Answer (score 1):

You did not do anything wrong. As you know, rebase is putting the changes from master on top of myBranch but to do that in the remote branch, you have to use `--force` which would basically delete all your commit and recommit all changes.

Your local branch will be used as the main source for remote/myBranch which is why you have to sync your local with your remote myBranch, hence the need for `--force`